# How to group values and turn their count into percentages and display them?

Tags: r

I have 2 columns, id, and accuracy_level.

`id <- c(1,2,5,2,4,6,5,2,8,7)`
`accuracy_level <- c(10,24,65,72,44,62,58,27,48,37)`

| id | accuracy_level |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 24 |
| 5 | 65 |
| 2 | 72 |
| 4 | 44 |
| 6 | 62 |
| 5 | 58 |
| 2 | 27 |
| 8 | 48 |
| 7 | 37 |

I want to display the percentage of ids that have different accuracy_level. Like 10% of the ids have accuracy_level of 0-20.

The plot should show, for example, 10%-20%-30%... on the x-axis and the ranges on the y-axis.

If there is a better way to tackle it please do mention it.

Thank You

Comment: Seems like you want a histogram with percentages rather than frequencies on the y-axis:  `hist(accuracy_level, freq=F, breaks=seq(0,100,10))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided by DanY in the comments.

"Seems like you want a histogram with percentages rather than frequencies on the y-axis: hist(accuracy_level, freq=F, breaks=seq(0,100,10))"